# Дополни код функции createArrayOfNumbers(min, max) JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Задание:

> Дополни код функции createArrayOfNumbers(min, max) так, чтобы она возвращала массив всех целых чисел от значения min до max.
>
> ```
> function createArrayOfNumbers(min, max) {
>   const numbers = [i];
>   // Change code below this line
>   for(let i=min; i<max; i += 1)
>   // Change code above this line
>   return numbers;
> }
> ```

Тесты:

> ```
> Объявлена функция createArrayOfNumbers(min, max)
> Вызов функции createArrayOfNumbers(1, 3) возвращает [1, 2, 3]
> Вызов функции createArrayOfNumbers(14, 17) возвращает [14, 15, 16, 17]
> Вызов функции createArrayOfNumbers(29, 34) возвращает [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
> Вызов функции createArrayOfNumbers() со случайными min и max возвращает правильный массив
> В цикле for использовался метод push
> ```

Подскажите, у меня каша не варится

Comment: добавьте `i` в массив в данном цикле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1.

```js
function createArrayOfNumbers(min, max){
  return Array.from({length: max-min+1}, (_,i)=> i+ min);
}


console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(1,3));
console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(14,17));
console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(29,34));
```

Вариант 2.

```js
function createArrayOfNumbers(min, max) {
  const numbers = [];
  for(let i = min;  i <= max; i++)
    numbers.push(i);
  return numbers;
}

console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(1,3));
console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(14,17));
console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(29,34));
```

к комментариям что проще, первый вариант можно написать в одну строчку. Но читать её конечно не просто.

```js
const createArrayOfNumbers = (min, max) => Array.from({length: max-min+1}, (_,i)=> i+ min);


console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(1,3));
console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(14,17));
console.log(createArrayOfNumbers(29,34));
```